# Real line with positive infinity adjoined: typeset more compactly

Tags: spacing, fontsize

For a document I am working on I frequently need to refer to the real line with positive infinity adjoined (but not negative infinity). I have been typesetting this as follows

`\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}`

[image]

This takes up a lot of horizontal space. Is there a way to get a smaller plus symbol? Or to cramp the symbols together a bit more? I just feel a bit bothered that, in the expressions where this space occurs, it doesn't really register visually as a discrete entity unto itself.

[image]

Comment: you could use `{\cup}` to lose the binop spacing but can't you define this to be R_\infinity or some such, and then just use the defined symbol?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not competent to say what this change might imply to the meaning, but to set the `\cup` as an "ordinary " character, eliminating all space, wrap it in braces: `{\cup}`.

Comment: Honestly it doesn't bother me. I'd use larger parentheses `\bigl(...\bigr)`. You can lose the spacing around `\cup` by enclosing it in braces `{\cup}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks! I thought about using something like R_infinity, but felt it should really be R_{+infinity} to avoid confusion with the one point compactification, and the latter looked too clunky for me. Anyway your other suggestions here and in your answer below are very helpful, so thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think I'd use the form you show, but if using it a lot make it a defined term such as R' then just use that defined notation.

But if you want to squeeze it, perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[C_0(\mathbb{R}{\scriptstyle \cup \{+ \infty\}}) \rtimes \mathbb{R}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Neat, I may use something like this! Thanks for indulging this rather frivolous question! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with a special symbol that conveys the idea:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\upcomp}{{{-}\!\!{\bullet}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\downcomp}{{{\bullet}\!\!{-}}}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\RRup}{\RR_{\upcomp}}
\newcommand{\RRdown}{\RR_{\downcomp}}

\begin{document}

We define $\RRup=\RR\cup\{+\infty\}$ and $\RRdown=\RR\cup\{-\infty\}$
with the topology induced by the usual extended real line.

Now we can use $C_0(\RRup)$ that takes less space.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative with `\mapsfromchar` of `stmaryrd`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\upcomp}{{-\mapsfromchar}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\downcomp}{{\mapstochar-}}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\RRup}{\RR_{\upcomp}}
\newcommand{\RRdown}{\RR_{\downcomp}}

\begin{document}

We define $\RRup=\RR\cup\{+\infty\}$ and $\RRdown=\RR\cup\{-\infty\}$
with the topology induced by the usual extended real line.

Now we can use $C_0(\RRup)$ that takes less space.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well worth considering. Thanks!